# How to handle Option in recursive functions in functional programming within Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, option-type

I recently picked up interests in functional programming, and I'm working with some toy script.

One example is, taking a list of integers, adding them up in sequence, and get the index when the rolling sum reaches a certain value, say -1.

This is what I have now:

```scala
@tailrec
def someFunc(currentSum: Int, list: List[Int], index: Int): Int = {
  if (currentSum == -1) return index
  // Return -1 if the value is never reached
  if (index >= list.length) return -1
  val value = list(index)
  someFunc(currentSum + value, list, index + 1)
}
```

This works, and if the rolling sum never reaches `-1`, function will return `-1`.

I'm not exactly happy with returning `-1` in this case, after some readings, I was introduced to the concept of `Option`, basically I could have `Some` value or `None`. I figured this might be the proper solution in this scenario, so I changed my code to this:

```scala
@tailrec
def someFunc(currentSum: Int, list: List[Int], index: Int): Option[Int] = {
  if (currentSum == -1) return Some(index)
  if (index >= list.length) return None
  val value = list(index)
  someFunc(currentSum + value, list, index + 1)
}
```

Now my question is, is there anything I can do to avoid adding `Some(index)` in the 3rd line? In this case it seems trivial, but for more complex situation, it seems a bit unnecessary to add `Some` everywhere down in the chain.

Also I'm also wondering if this is the proper functional way to handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is this: ""I should just be able type `return index` instead of typing `return Some(index)`, and scala-compiler should understand that since this function returns a Option, so I actually mean the latter"".

> it seems a bit unnecessary to add `Some` everywhere

It is not unnecessary. If what you ask is fulfilled, this will result in ambiguity. Consider this scenario:

```
def hypotheticalFunction(....): Option[Option[Int]]: = {
  if (some-condition ) return None --> ambigious
  // more code
}
```

Does the `return None` mean `return Some(None)` or `return None`? We have no way of knowing.

==========================================

> Also I'm also wondering if this is the proper functional way to handle this type of situation?

I can think of at least 2 improvements:

1. Generally return statements are discouraged, code-readability can take a setback by arbitrary breaking of function flow by a `return`. You can use this:

```
if (condition) Some(index)
else if (condition) None
else { 

}
```

2. Since earlier parts of list is not needed in recursive calls, you can only send the tail of the the list to the recursive function. In this way, you won't have to iterate the list by calling `list(index)`. Some snippet:

```
@tailrec
def someFunc(currentSum: Int, list: List[Int], index: Int): Option[Int] = {
  if (currentSum == -1) Some(index)
  else if (list.isEmpty) None
  else {
    val value = list.head
    someFunc(currentSum + value, list.tail, index + 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for actually translating my questions into a proper way, `If what you ask is fulfilled, this will result in ambiguity` this makes total sense as you showcased.  About the `return` thing, I usually preferred early return instead of multiple else-if but I guess that's a flavor thing, second tips very valid and helpful!

Comment: @lanrete `return` is bad. Don't use it. Just pretend that keyword does not exist at all

Comment: For @lanrete `return` is not only not required, [it is discouraged](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html). For lanrete & beira, you may use [**pattern matching**] instead of checking for `empty` like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/FpO8IeomQXKdEjv9LmRD2A/3).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the document and link, any specific reason why you define your outer function as `func(n: Int)(data: List[Int])` instead of `func(n: Int, data: List[Int])`?

Comment: @lanrete not a big one, I usually try to curry configuration from data just because. Actually, my original idea was to define the function as an extension method on the list type _(that is why the method name is in such way that `n` is the first & only argument)_ but then I thought doing that would probably just confuse you more and obscure the real intention.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "everywhere down the chain". There are pretty much just two cases - either `Some` or `None`. And yeah, you have to specify which is which.

A pattern match can make this case separation a bit clearer (it also fixes a problem with your implementation making it quadratic: `List` is a link list, and `list(index)` is linear, don't do that):

```
def someFunc(
  list: List[Int], 
  currentSum: Int = 0,
  index: Int=0
): Option[Int] = list match {
   case _ if currentSum == -1 => Some(index)
   case Nil => None
   case head :: tail => someFunc(tail, currentSum + head, index+1)
}
```